# Prove a recursive function $f(p_i) = (p_i/2)g(p_i) \to \infty$ as $p_i \to \infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, discrete-mathematics, recursion, computational-mathematics

Let's say we have a set of numbers $\{5,9,13,17,21,\ldots, 5+4i,\ldots\}$ and each $p_i$ is a member of this set, namely $p_0 = 5, p_1 = 9, p_2 = 13$ , etc.

Consider the following functions defined recursively:
\begin{align}
g(p_i) &= \frac{p_i - 2}{p_i} g(p_{i-1}) & g(5) &= \frac35 \\
f(p_i) &= \frac{ p_i}2 g(p_i) &&
\end{align}

How does one prove that $f(p_i)$ goes to infinity as $p_i$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I would try computing the first values, and then try to prove, using induction on $i$ a statement of the form "for all $i\geq 5$, $f(p_i)\geq ci$ for some constant $c$ (that you would somehow guess computing the first terms).